# How do I automatically click link inside iFrame containing Google search results?

Tags: javascript

This is a tough one.... for me.

I have a link from a video on YouTube. When someone clicks it, it will navigate to a page containing an iFrame that has a google search results preloaded. Then after 3 seconds my link from the search results is clicked automatically from the search list just like someone click it. Then hopefully my page will move up in ranking and I will rule the world. Not to sure if this can be done.

This is what I have so far.
It still need JS to wait 3 seconds and go click link from the search results. Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=independent+financial+news&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8" name="Name"
width="1000" height="1200">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot do anything inside an iFrame that does not have the same domain as the container page.  Also, you have no code  of what you have tried.

Comment: "Then hopefully my page will move up in ranking and I will rule the world.".  Thank you for providing your motivation, it has helped many people decide not to help you.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do would violate the same origin policy and probably would be considered click fraud by Google.